# Clash between bibentry and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, option-clash, bibentry

Created a document that cites a number of publications within text using the bibentry package. Then I noticed that the zoom was set too large. Thought I could fix this using the hyperref package but this seems to introduce some sort of conflict.

Below is some code that replicates the problem along with a sample reference.

Hope someone can help me understand what's going wrong here. Tried researching this online but didn't find anything that seemed to address this particular problem.

Thanks,

Paul

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}}
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\nobibliography{ResumeBibliography}

\subsection*{Sample Referefence}

\bibentry{Goossens1994LaTeX} 

\end{document}


@book{Goossens1994LaTeX,
  author = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
  title = {The \LaTeX{} Companion, $2^{nd}$ Edition},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1994{.}}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load `natbib` (of which `bibentry` is a subpackage) and change `abbrv` to `abbrvnat`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Goossens1994LaTeX,
  author = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
  title = {The \LaTeX{} Companion, $2^{nd}$ Edition},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1994{.}}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}}
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\nobibliography{\jobname}

\subsection*{Sample Reference}

\bibentry{Goossens1994LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

Note, the `filecontents*` environment is just for making the example self-contained; use your bib file.

[image]

Comment: This is very straightforward and works both in my example code and in my original document. Thank you very much for your help with this. Paul