# hyperref and bibentry problems in res class

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, resume, bibentry

Similar to this question: [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81937/hyperref-bibentry-natbib-conflict-incorrect-hyperlink), and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145360/clash-between-bibentry-and-hyperref), but it did not help me.

UPDATE: I am specifically looking for the res class. However, I do not care if bibentry is used or something else.

I cannot compile references, the problem seems to be with bibentry, hyperref, and the bibliography files. The code results either in an error or compiles but the references are not printed out, depending on whether hyperref is loaded before or after bibentry.

Here is a MWE where I removed all other details. This produces the relevant errors.

```
   \documentclass[10pt]{res}
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=0.8in,right=1.2in]{geometry}


\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother


\usepackage{enumitem}


\nobibliography{thebib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\usepackage[hidelinks,pagebackref=true,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}


\section{\sc Publications}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \bibentry{singh2019popov}

\end{enumerate}

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

And this is the bibtex file called `thebib.bib`

```
 @Article{singh2019popov,
  author  = {Singh, Bismark},
  title   = {{Popov, Berg, Sokolov}: A Street with Three Plaques},
  journal = {The Mathematical Intelligencer},
  year    = {2019},
  volume  = {41},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {13--15},
  month   = {Dec},
  issn    = {1866-7414},
  day     = {01},
  doi     = {10.1007/s00283-019-09936-1},
  url     = {https://doi.org/10.1007/s00283-019-09936-1},
}
```

Comment: hi! i ran your code on my computer. i am able to compile it if the commands 
`\nobibliography{thebib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`
are inside the document environment.
I also had to change `\nobibliography{thebib}` to `\bibliography{thebib}`, but that's probably due to some package i'm missing. 
Can you try running it again with those two commands inside the document environment and tell us the result?

Comment: @ArakTog If those two lines are inside, then I get Bibtex finished with error code 1 and a warning label singh2019popov is multiply defined, even though its defined only once...

Comment: hum. is it possible you have multiple thebib.bib files?

Comment: And I get the error:  File ended while scanning use of \BR@c@bibitem.

Comment: Ok. i've been trying multiple options. can you tell me if the following runs in your computer?

`\documentclass[10pt]{article}`


`\usepackage{bibentry}`

`\begin{document}`

`\nobibliography{thebib}`
`\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`

`Some text here. My publications:`
`\begin{itemize}`
`\item \bibentry{singh2019popov}`
`\item \bibentry{singh2019popov}`
`\end{itemize}`

`Some other text.`

`\end{document} `

Comment: @ArakTog thanks for trying - but I definitely need the res class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104418/discussion-between-bissi-and-arak-tog).

Comment: the res.cls is from 2000 (and it isn't in a current texlive as it is not free). It issues a \nofiles which means that it doesn't work with any package which needs to write to the aux. I wouldn't spent time to try to sort this out. Such old code should be dropped. Switch to a newer system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you have an almost exact equivalent of the res class? I do not know one, unless I want to completely revamp my resume.

Comment: well you will have to revamp something as it doesn't work. res.cls is old, bibentry is old and both not or not fully compatible to hyperref. I would say it is much easier to start with biblatex + hyperref and to use a newer, compatible class.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unfortunately your answer does not add to my post, as I am specifically looking for something that mirrors the res class. Since your answers do not contribute, I am closing this discussion.

Comment: I didn't answer, I only commented that I think that you should look for a different solution. There is no need "to close a discussion"; you are quite free to ignore my comments.